# case details field not available through UI

Tags: civicase

Is it true that the Case Details field can be populated, but cannot be seen through the UI in CiviCRM?

This seems odd - if it's true I'll open an issue in gitlab, but wanted to check in with the community first.

It seems like it can be pulled into a view or webform, but not viewed in Civi!

Answer (score 1):

It's initially populated with the details of the open case activity and depending on your philosophy should or shouldn't be linked with the open case activity. In the [compucorp](https://github.com/compucorp/uk.co.compucorp.civicase) version of civicase you can see/edit it.

Comment: OK - thanks Demerit, that puts a lot more into perspective + the knowledge that it's not just me missing the obvious. My sanity is saved, at least.